# Synergy 1.4.2 locks up server machine w/out connection

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.10, synergy

If the connection between the server (in my case Windows 7 64bit, synergy 1.4.2) and the client (Ubuntu 10.10, synergy 1.4.2) is lost the pointer and keyboard stay on the client machine, making shutting down/ restarting synergy impossible. The only way to get either system to respond to output again is to click the power button on the front of the PC and wait for Windows 7 to shut the synergy process down.

Answer (score 0):

I only have Synergy 1.3.4, but when I start the synergy server screen, I can hit the options button and check the "Check clients every ____ ms" checkbox and if it can't get a response, then it will disconnect that client and return control to me.